# style.backgroundImage javascript method not working for me on any browser (FireFox, Chrome, IE, Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styles, background-image

I can change the background image with css but in this case i need to use javascript,
Imgae Name is "btn1-1.png" and its in the "img" directory(child directory) where is my HTML index file is in Parent Directory, Image path is working in css but not in Javascript

```
  <input type="button" id="btn_1" class="btn_hidder" value="Information" />
  <input type="button" id="btn_2" class="btn_hidder" value="Documents" />
```

And here is JavaScript code...

```
document.getElementById("btn_1").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/btn1-1.png')";
```

Check screen shots as well.
Parent Directory (HTML File): http://i60.tinypic.com/2dkzk9y.jpg 
 Child Directory (JS File): http://i60.tinypic.com/14wf237.jpg

My script is added perfectly because its working with alert() as well as all other JavaScript code is working. I also tried Internal way for JavaScript but nothing happen.

Comment: Your js should be in another directory.

Comment: Using absolute URL usually solves this kind of issues, unless you're not trying to refer a button before it exists.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you didn't ask for it, but I love jquery. Note: I didn't test this. You still might have the path issue as stated by Billy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn_1').css('background-image', 'img/btn1-1.png');
});
```

Comment: Thanx, I am going with JQ now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `document.getElementById("btn_1").style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/btn1-1.png')";` as the js is in the js folder, Which is up one level, then down one into images folder.

Answer (score 0):

here @billy is right

you have to tell them where to in right way

1)  '../' means go back up a directory.

2)  './' means stay in this directory

3)  '/' on its own means go back to the root directory.

so you have to use

```
document.getElementById("btn_1").style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/btn1-1.png')";
```

Comment: I am using:     document.getElementById("btn_1").style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/btn1-1.png')";

Comment: use 'hit & try' method by using above 3 methods ,sometimes it works.

Comment: Thanks, but i finally decided to go with JQ